# Android: Intent problem

Tags: android, android-intent

Debugging the following piece of code I get "Source not found" notification which probably means some variables are not set:

```
btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), DlgTitleTags.class);
            intent.putExtra(Client.STORED_TITLE, mTitle);
            intent.putExtra(Client.STORED_TAGS, mTags);
            startActivityForResult(intent, SHOW_SUBACTIVITY_TITLE_TAGS);

        }

    });
```

Here intent is successfully created and all other varables are set as well so I'm still trying to figure out what causes the problem.

I noticed the log messages:

```
07-28 13:29:09.642: DEBUG/dalvikvm(56): GC freed 2010 objects / 86744 bytes in 230ms
07-28 13:29:14.861: WARN/WindowManager(56): Key dispatching timed out sending to dev.client.android/dev.client.android.DlgEditFile
07-28 13:29:14.862: WARN/WindowManager(56): Dispatch state: {{KeyEvent{action=1 code=4 repeat=0 meta=0 scancode=158 mFlags=8} to Window{43377460 dev.client.android/dev.client.android.DlgEditFile paused=false} @ 1248780547618 lw=Window{43377460 dev.client.android/dev.client.android.DlgEditFile paused=false} lb=android.os.BinderProxy@43449e78 fin=false gfw=true ed=true tts=0 wf=false fp=false mcf=Window{43377460 dev.client.android/dev.client.android.DlgEditFile paused=false}}}
07-28 13:29:14.862: WARN/WindowManager(56): Current state:  {{null to Window{43377460 dev.client.android/dev.client.android.DlgEditFile paused=false} @ 1248780554868 lw=Window{43377460 dev.client.android/dev.client.android.DlgEditFile paused=false} lb=android.os.BinderProxy@43449e78 fin=false gfw=true ed=true tts=0 wf=false fp=false mcf=Window{43377460 dev.client.android/dev.client.android.DlgEditFile paused=false}}}
07-28 13:29:14.872: WARN/WindowManager(56): Continuing to wait for key to be dispatched
07-28 13:29:15.212: INFO/ActivityManager(56): Starting activity: Intent { comp={dev.client.android/dev.client.android.DlgTitleTags} (has extras) }
07-28 13:29:15.522: WARN/ResourceType(1647): Failure getting entry for 0x7f030005 (t=2 e=5) in package 0: 0xffffffb5
```

I would really appreciate any help in solving the problem.

Comment: Could you post a bigger snippet of LogCat? One that shows the exception thats being thrown...

Comment: Did you find out the cause? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

most likely your activity DlgTitleTags is not defined in the Manifest.

Comment: it is defined in the Manifest

Answer (score 1):

1. open the **AndroidManifest.xml**
2. at the bottom add another **Activity**
3. once added, click the activity and on the right side besides **Name**
4. click browse and select the other class file (.java file)